# Split xml to several output files

Tags: xslt, altova, map-force

Simplistically, I have xml that contains 120 nodes. How can I create 3 xml files that have 50 nodes in each? I've marked output as dynamic. Then I've tried to apply `auto-number` function but I can't get when it fires and how to create condition on it. What I need is sthm like trigger that would cause creation of new file. My strategy:

[image]

P.S. I'm noob at MapForce.

Comment: Could you share your input/output schema and a sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is

```
<root>
    <elt>...</elt>
    ...
</root>
```

then simplistically, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:document href="1-50.xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/elt[pos() &lt;= 50]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:document>

    <xsl:document href="51-100.xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/elt[pos() >= 51 and pos() &lt;= 100]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:document>

    <!-- repeat for other portions of input -->
</xsl:template>
```

In practice, you'd want to be a little bit smarter to handle arbitrary numbers of nodes in the input.

Comment: THanks, but actually it's very straight-forward approach, even simplistically ). My goal is to dynamically create output xml's using Altova Mapforce.